# Loop through the file as long as the userinput is same as string in the file

Tags: java, while-loop

Hey I'm working on a Bank account application and i'm working on the login at the moment. I want the Programm to go through the file and check if there is already a username same as the one the user wants, if there is one it should go back and ask for a new username again. I've tried many different ways but i couldn't find one that works. I hope someone can help me. :-)

```
    String file = "C:\\Users\\dsociety\\IdeaProjects\\bankaccount\\logins.txt";
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    BufferedReader on = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String username;
    String pw;


    Boolean exists = false;
    Scanner scanner = null;
    try {
        scanner = new Scanner(new File(file));
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println("Please enter a username");
    username = in.readLine();

    BufferedReader bru = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String line;

    try {
        while (exists == true) {
            while ((line = bru.readLine()) != null) {
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
                    String[] userAndPw = scanner.nextLine().split(":");
                    String user = userAndPw[0];

                    if (user.equals(username)) {
                        System.out.println("There is already a User with that username, please try a other username");
                        exists = false;
                    }
                    else {
                        exists = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        bru.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    System.out.println("Please enter a password");
    pw = on.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked through your code and, as someone else noticed, you can't enter the first while loop because of the `exists` variable being false. And I think you messed the order of the `while`s a little bit.
You definitely don't need a `Scanner` *and* a `BufferedReader` (one of them is enough) for reading the file, just as how you don't need two different `BufferedReader`s to read from the system input (again, one is sufficient).
I modified your code a little bit and added some comments and I hope it works for you now:

```
    String file = "C:\\logins.txt";
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    String username;
    String pw;

    System.out.println("Please enter a username");

    BufferedReader bru = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
    // we will keep the users here instead of reading the file everytime a username is entered
    List<String> users = new ArrayList<>();

    Boolean exists = null;
    String line;

    // populate the existing users list by reading all the lines in the file
    while ((line = bru.readLine()) != null) {
        users.add(line.split(":")[0]);
    }

    bru.close();

    // we can enter the while loop if we are asking for the username for the first time
    // or if the username entered already exists
    while (exists == null || exists == true) {
        // we read the username from the input
        username = in.readLine();
        // we suppose it doesn't already exist
        exists = false;
        // we look at every existing user
        for (String user : users) {
            /*
             * if the names are the same, we don't need to look further, we know the username
             * exists and so we will break from the "for" loop and ask for a username once again
             * (side note: I used replaceAll in order to remove all invisible unicode characters
             * that might make two strings unequal that would otherwise be identical)
             */
            if (user.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", "").equals(username.replaceAll("\\P{Print}", ""))) {
                System.out.println("There is already a User with that username, please try a other username");
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    }

    System.out.println("Please enter a password");
    pw = in.readLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to divide the job in two parts:

1. Scan through the file for every username. Put username as `key` in a map.
2. Ask for input username, and check if the username is present or not.

   ```
   if (myMap.containsKey(username) == true) {
      // ...
   } else {
      // Go back to step 2
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this code will help to solve your issue:

```
private static boolean userExists(String consoleParam){

    String filePath = "C:\\Users\\dsociety\\IdeaProjects\\bankaccount\\logins.txt";
    File file = null;
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;
    Boolean exists = false;

    try{

        file = new File (filePath);
        fr = new FileReader (file);
        br = new BufferedReader(fr);

        String line;
        while((line=br.readLine())!=null){
            if(line.split(":")[0].equals(consoleParam)){
                exists = true;
                break;
            }
        }

    }catch(Exception e){
         e.printStackTrace();
    }finally{
       /* Close opened resources */
       try{                    
          if( null != fr ){   
             fr.close();     
          }

       }catch (Exception e2){ 
          e2.printStackTrace();
       }  
    }

    return exists;

}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean newUser = false;

    /* Check if username alredy exists */
    while(!newUser){

        System.out.println("Please enter a username"); 
        String username = reader.next();
        newUser = !userExists(username);

    }

    /* Close resources */
    System.out.println("New username entered!");
    reader.close();

}
```